# (ArrayAdapter maybe) / / 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I'm a beginner and also it is my first app. I am trying to do a To Do List app.Now, I stuck and I can't find my mistake. Can some one help me about this?

**EDITED**

asilajandaActivity.java

```
public class asilajandaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TaskDbHelper mHelper;
private ListView mTaskListView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle(R.string.title_activity_asilajanda);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_asilajanda);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mHelper = new TaskDbHelper(this);
    mTaskListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_todo);

    updateUI();updateUI2();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_add_task:



            final Dialog dialog= new Dialog(this);


            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialod_ajanda);
            dialog.setTitle("Etkinlik Ekle");
            final EditText dateEditText=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            final EditText taskEditText =(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.Text);

            Button kaydet= (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button4);
            Button vazgec=(Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button5);



            kaydet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    try {
                        SQLiteDatabase db= mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                        ContentValues values1 = new ContentValues();
                        String date = String.valueOf(dateEditText.getText());
                        values1.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_tar, date);

                        db.insertWithOnConflict(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE, null, values1, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                        try {
                            SQLiteDatabase db= mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                            String date = String.valueOf(taskEditText.getText());
                            values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE, date);

                            db.insertWithOnConflict(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
                        } catch (Exception e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    db.close();
                    updateUI();updateUI2();
                    dialog.dismiss();

                }

            });

            vazgec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                 public void onClick(View v){
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
                    dialog.create();
            dialog.show();

            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}


public void deleteTask(View view) {
    View parent = (View) view.getParent();
    TextView taskTextView = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
    TextView tarihtext =(TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.tarih_text);
    String task = String.valueOf(taskTextView.getText());
    String date = String.valueOf(tarihtext.getText());
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,
            TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE + " = ?",
            new String[]{task});
    db.delete(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,
            TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_tar,
                    new String[]{date});


    db.close();
    updateUI2();
    updateUI();
}

private void updateUI() {
    ArrayList<String> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,
            new String[]{TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID, TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_tar},
            null, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
      int idx1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_tar);
        taskList.add(cursor.getString(idx1));


    }


    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                R.layout.item_todo,
                R.id.task_title,
                taskList);
        mTaskListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    } else {
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(taskList);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}
private void updateUI2() {
    ArrayList<String> dateList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor2 = db.query(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,
            new String[]{TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID, TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE},
            null, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor2.moveToNext()) {
        int idx = cursor2.getColumnIndex(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE);
        dateList.add(cursor2.getString(idx));


    }


    if (mAdapter2 == null) {
        mAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                R.layout.item_todo,
                R.id.task_title,
                dateList);
        mTaskListView.setAdapter(mAdapter2);
    } else {
        mAdapter2.clear();
        mAdapter2.addAll(dateList);
        mAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    cursor2.close();
    db.close();
}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
07-28 04:04:16.722 25806-25806/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
```

> 07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:401)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1280)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1188)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:735)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>   07-28 04:56:15.284 27235-27235/com.lidenoapp.ajanda E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

I read other questions which are about `NullPointerExpection` but i can't find something that can help me. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Careful when you use String date = String.valueOf(dateEditText.getText()); if you put a null as input for the function, it will crash. Do the following

```
try {
            String date = String.valueOf(dateEditText.getText());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: or you can do TextUtils.isEmpty() to check if the string input is valid.

Comment: I tried it and didnt work :( (I am not sure that write correct )

Comment: then you have to find out which line does make your app crash. remove update UI and UpdateUI2, see if still crash. Do you know how to use debug mode, put in breakpoints, so you know which line of your code crash. NullPointerExpection can be thrown in many way, can be in String.ValueOf, can be you provide an null list for your adapter. etc.